# How can I use PyCharm (Python) to access a Raspberry Pi that is on a different network

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ip, remote-access, pigpio

The code below in PyCharm only works if the PC and Raspberry Pi are on the same network.
If I want the Raspberry Pi to be on a different network, what changes should I make to the code for that to work?

```py
from gpiozero import LED, Button  
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory  
from time import sleep  
  
factory=PiGPIOFactory(host='192.168.182.240')  
GPIO17=LED(17,pin_factory=factory)
```

Answer (score 0):

After network changed, try to `ping` the new IP address of Pi

1. if the `ping` test passed, replace `host='192.168.182.240'` with the new IP.
2. if failed, i recommand you to install zerotier on both PC and Pi, and connect to Pi via virtual lan ip provided by zerotier.